# How to set location in HTTParty

Tags: ruby, httparty

We have a method that scrapes pages using a table of URL's with HTTParty. Sometimes the pages it scrapes are in fact redirected to the homepage of the German version of the site. Our server is based in Germany, and I suspect that this is the cause as the method works fine when run from my local in the UK. Is there any way to set the browsing location of HTTParty to the UK in the same way that you can set the user agent browser type?

```
HTTParty.get(URI::escape(link), :headers => {"User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17"})
```

Comment: It depends on how they are actually detecting the language to use : IP address (the only easy solution I can think about could be to connect through a proxy) or Accept-Language header.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jef. I just tried setting the accept-language header to no avail. I will look into using a proxy.